# Problem about the vectorial wave equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

I have a homework where i have to study the vectorial wave equation $$\begin{cases} \partial_t U + LU = 0,  \ & (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2, \ t>0\\ U(x,y,0)=U_0(x,y), \  & (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \end{cases}$$
with $$L= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & \partial_x & \partial_y \\
                          \partial_x & 0 & 0 \\
                          \partial_y & 0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$$
and $U_0(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^3$.
I have 2 questions that i'm struggling with.
First, we consider the fourier formula
$$U(\mathbf{x},t) = \frac{1}{4\pi^2} \int_{\mathbf{k}\in \mathbb{R}^2} \hat{U}(\mathbf{k},t)e^{i (\mathbf{k},\mathbf{x})} dk_1 dk_2, \ \ \hat{U}(\mathbf{k},t)=\int_{\mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{R}^2} U(\mathbf{x},t)e^{-i(\mathbf{k},\mathbf{x})} dxdy
$$ where $\mathbf{x}=(x,y)$ and $\mathbf{k}=(k_1,k_2)$ are the space and fourier variable.
I'm asked to show "formally" that $$\frac{d}{dt} \hat{U}(\mathbf{k},t)=-\hat{L}\hat{U}(\mathbf{k},t)$$ with $$\hat{L}= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & ik_1 & ik_2 \\ ik_1 & 0 & 0 \\ ik_2 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
So i tried this : \begin{align}\frac{d}{dt} \hat{U}(\mathbf{k},t) &=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \frac{d}{dt} U(\mathbf{x},t)e^{-i(\mathbf{k},\mathbf{x})} dxdy \\ &=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} -LU(\mathbf{x},t)e^{-i(\mathbf{k},\mathbf{x})} dxdy .
\end{align}
And i'm stucked here, i know that the matrix $\hat{L}$ should comes out when i apply $L$ to the $e^{-i(\mathbf{k},\mathbf{x})}$ term but my issue is that L is only applied to $U$ here.

My second question, i had to show that $$
\hat{U}(\mathbf{k},t)= \left[ I - \hat{L} \frac{\sin(\vert \mathbf{k} \vert t)}{\vert \mathbf{k} \vert} - \hat{L^2} \frac{\cos(\vert \mathbf{k} \vert t) -1}{\vert \mathbf{k} \vert ^2} \right] \hat{U}_0(\mathbf{k})$$, then i have to assume that $(1+\vert \mathbf{k} \vert )U_0 \in L^2(\mathbb{R})^3$ and show that $\partial_t U \in L^2(\mathbb{R})^3$ and $LU \in L^2 (\mathbb{R})^3$. I tried this :
$$ U(\mathbf{x},t) = \frac{1}{4\pi^2} \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \left[ I - \hat{L} \frac{\sin(\vert \mathbf{k} \vert t)}{\vert \mathbf{k} \vert} - \hat{L^2} \frac{\cos(\vert \mathbf{k} \vert t) -1}{\vert \mathbf{k} \vert ^2} \right] \hat{U_0}(\mathbf{k}) dk_1 dk_2 $$
so $$\frac{d}{dt} U(\mathbf{x},t)= \frac{1}{4\pi^2} \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} -\hat{L}\hat{U}_0(\mathbf{k}) \cos(\vert \mathbf{k} \vert t) e^{i(\mathbf{k}, \mathbf{x})}+\hat{L}^2 \hat{U}_0(\mathbf{k}) \frac{\sin(\vert \mathbf{k} \vert t)}{\vert \mathbf{k} \vert } e^{i(\mathbf{k},\mathbf{x})} dk_1 dk_2.
$$
Then i tried to express the $L^2$-norm of this expression but this didn't get me anywhere.
Any hint would be greatly appreciated